# JavaScript not working on Chrome or on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

Hi~I'm working on my personal website.

I want to realize an "image slide show" effect with a java script that i downloaded.

It works well on IE, but it doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox.

PS: the original downloaded file works well on Chrome, but after i placing it to my site, the problem comes.

here is my site: http://iphrog.244213.dprktimes.com/
here is the java script sample code: http://iphrog.244213.dprktimes.com/index2.html

they use the same js file, but the js file doesn't work on chrome for my site.

Whats the problem?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fiphrog.244213.dprktimes.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 says that there are errors in your html code (div closed in line 66 which is not open). Maybe you want to fix that error first.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what strikes me is: if I hover with the mouse over the images, the mouse pointer does not changed. So for some reason, the <a> tags are not recognized. My guess would be that there is something wrong with your css or your html. Could there be some "transparent" item lying in front of your images which makes clicks not being recognized?

Comment: @JohnB I'm sure there is.  It's impossible to inspect the arrow element without sorting through the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `div` with the id of `content` has a `z-index` of -1000.  This is causing it to not detect any of the clicks on your elements, as it is 'behind everything'.  Remove this style, set it to 0 or set it to a non-negative number, and your script works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But new problem comes, lol. I used " z-index ", because i want that the shadow of the header part is above the content part...if i set z-index to 0，the content part is above the shadow.

Comment: I've solved that shadow problem by myself! Thanks a lot! @Daedalus